# Book about a tribal village that falls under the influence of a malevolent priest

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

The book I'm searching for is about a young woman who lives in a village that is part of a larger tribe. She is part of a tribal police/army type-force, which I believe is made up of the village's young adults. The members of this force have some sort of hive-mind magic. She has a large family, most of whom were craftsmen and women. She herself is skilled in making jewellery, I believe.

The village falls under the influence of a malevolent priest, who manipulates the protagonist for some time by casting a sort of spell on her. She eventually breaks free of this spell, and she and some members of her family escape through hidden tunnels underneath the village. The houses in the village are made of stone, and the people live in a cold climate.

If anyone has any idea what book this may be, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you remember when you read the book and how old it was?

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: I read it about 4 years ago, but I'm not sure when the book was published